# Get rows with values on JSONB and also if rows if the value does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table called `credentials` which has a `jsonb` column called `details` and a column called `user_id`. The `details` column has an array called `systems` which it can be either empty, or contain objects that look like this: `{ system_id: TXT, system_value: TXT }`

I have the following query that pretends to get all the system_values for a given system_id for each of the users:

```
SELECT credentials.user_id, systems->>'system_value' AS system_value
FROM  credentials, jsonb_array_elements(credentials.details->'systems') systems
WHERE systems->>'system_id' = 'a-given-id'
```

This works fine. However, if a user either:

1. Does not have any objects inside the `credentials` array OR
2. Does not have an object with the given `system_id`

It does not return a row for them. I would like to return a row that says `system_value` is `NULL`.

So, for example, for the given data:

```
user_id, credentials
1, { "systems": [{ "system_id": "x", "system_value": "success" }] }
2, { "systems": [{ "system_id": "y", "system_value": "failure" }] }
3, { "systems": [] }
```

I would expect after my query to get:

```
user_id, system_value
1, "success"
2, NULL
3, NULL
```

But with my current query, I am just getting:

```
user_id, system_value
1, "success"
```

How should I modify the query to take into account those credentials that don't have either values on 'systems' or none of the values for the given 'system_id'?

Notice that even if I do:

```
SELECT credentials.user_id, systems->>'system_value' AS system_value
FROM  credentials, jsonb_array_elements(credentials.details->'systems') systems
```

It won't return the users which don't have `credentails.details` with any elements at all. So I don't think the `where` is the issue.

Comment: Have you tried:  `WHERE systems->>'system_id' = 'a-given-id' or systems->>'system_id'  IS NULL`?

Comment: Yes. Actually even without the WHERE condition. It just returns the credentials that have a elements on details systems. If there is no elements at all it doesn't return it :( I think it has something to do with `jsonb_array_elements`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN ... ON true` to get all rows:

```
SELECT credentials.user_id, systems->>'system_value' AS system_value
FROM  credentials
LEFT JOIN jsonb_array_elements(credentials.details->'systems') systems ON true

 user_id | system_value 
---------+--------------
       1 | success
       2 | failure
       3 | 
(3 rows)
```

If you want to get all rows with values for a given `system_id` you should use a conditional expression in `SELECT`, as a condition in `WHERE` just filters rows:

```
SELECT 
    c.user_id, 
    CASE systems->>'system_id'
        WHEN 'x' THEN systems->>'system_value' 
        ELSE null
    END AS system_value
FROM  credentials c
LEFT JOIN jsonb_array_elements(c.details->'systems') systems ON true

 user_id | system_value 
---------+--------------
       1 | success
       2 | 
       3 | 
(3 rows)
```

[Try it in rextester.](https://rextester.com/PQDWT71442)

Comment: Amazing! That's exactly what I needed. Thank you very much